# Update picture/image in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to create update image for user who want to change their photo.The when i click submit on photo upload, there is no photo uploaded and photo's column still no update.

Here is my Contorller:

```
function foto($id='')
    {
        $data['data']        = $this->user_model->get_foto($id);
        $data['form_action'] = site_url("user/update_foto/$id");
        $this->load->view('user/foto_form', $data);
    }

    function update_foto($id=''){
        $this->user_model->update_foto($id);
    }
```

Here is My model:

```
function get_foto($id=0){
        $id    = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $sql   = "SELECT id,foto FROM user WHERE id= '$id'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $data  = $query->row_array();
        return $data;
    }

    function update_foto(){
        $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('foto'))
        {
            $id_user=$this->session->userdata('id');
            redirect ("user/foto/$id_user");
        }   else {
            $id_user=$this->session->userdata('id');
            $data=array(
            'foto'=>$this->input->post('foto')
            );
            $this->db->where('id',$id_user);
            $this->db->update('user',$data);
            redirect("user");
        }
    }
```

And this is my upload form on view:

```
    <form role="form" action="<?php echo $form_action ?>" class="form-horizontal style-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label >Upload Foto</label>
    <input type="file" name="foto"/>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
   </form>
```

Any Answer? Many thanks for the answer...

Comment: `<button>`'s do not cause a form submit. Try changing that to `<input type="submit"......?`

Comment: If this is valid solution, also could be solved adding name attribute: `<button name="submit" type="submit" value="Save">Save</button>`.

Answer (score 0):

On your controller try replacing this

from

```
site_url("user/update_foto/$id");
```

to

```
site_url("user/update_foto") ./. $id;
```

Or you could use uri segment refer user guide.

```
site_url("user/update_foto") ./. $this->uri->segment(4); // unsure id check uri segment in url.
```

Your route may need to be changed

`$route['user/update_foto/(:any)'] = "controllername/foto/$1";`

All ways make sure the controller has index()

Answer (score 0):

At your model this is wrong.

```
$data=array(
  'foto'=>$this->input->post('foto')
);
```

`$this->input->post('foto')` does not get your file name.
You can try that with this

```
 else {
        $id_user=$this->session->userdata('id');
        $info=$this->upload->data();
        $data=array(
        'foto'=>$info['file_name']
        );
        $this->db->where('id',$id_user);
        $this->db->update('user',$data);
        redirect("user");
    }
```

better use this line for your upload path

```
  $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'upload/';
```

Answer (score 0):

$file_name = "";

```
    if ($_FILES['foto']['error']!= 4) {

        $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['foto']['name']);
        $file_name = time() . '.' . $fileParts['extension'];
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';

        $config['file_name'] = $file_name;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('foto');
    }
```